# xdebug not working in MAMP Pro 3.5.2?

Tags: macos, xdebug, php-7, macos-sierra, mamp-pro

I have MAMP installed on my mac PC and running fine with PHP 7.0.8, I am trying to install xdebug on my mac PC and I successfully installed it but it is not working and give me this error when I run another command with php?

```
Failed loading /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/opcache.so:  dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/opcache.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_signal_globals
  Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/opcache.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/opcache.so
```

Anybody who face the same issue and solved it, Please help me to remove this error and run xdebug with MAMP Pro 3.5.2.